# Binary search not working cant find issue

Tags: javascript

```
        <script>
function DM(x){
    document.write(x)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    var low = 0;
    var high = 500;
    var found = false;
    var indexB = 0;
    var rooterArray= [];
    var squaryness = true

    for(index=1;index<500;index++){
        var holder = index * index;
        rooterArray[index-1] = holder;
    };
    var isSquare = parseFloat(prompt("enter a number less then 250000"));
        while(low < high && !found){    
            indexB=(low + high)/2; 
            indexB = Math.floor(indexB)
            if(rooterArray[indexB] == isSquare){  
                found = true;
                document.write("Match was found subscript: "+indexB);
            }
            else{
                if(rooterArray[indexB] > isSquare){
                    high = indexB - 1;  
                }   
                else{
                    low = indexB + 1; 
                }
            }
        } 
        if(!found){ 
            document.write("dude obv not a perfect square");
        }
    </script>
```

Code is just meant to check if the number you entered is a perfect square and inform you using binary search and an array but will only display "Sorry, value was not found"
edit: with slight changes, random ones work properly while others do not, think it may have something to do with math.floor but not 100%
as far as my testing goes, 1 works, 4, does not, 9 works, 16 does not, 25 works, 36 does not, so it would seem even numbers do not work. 
I created a function that runs the while loop, made a second array, but used the for loop for that one beginning at index 0, and it and it worked but its sort of disgusting, it raises two issues, indexes are not accurat, for example, both 4 and 1 have the same index, and it doesnt write anything if its not a perfect square

Comment: Is this code complete, did you forget to copy some of the code?

Comment: There's a syntax error at the `"enter a number less then 250000)` part, you need to close the quotes.

Comment: some of it but the error should be within the while loop that's doing the search, because it works when i use sequential searching.

Comment: the syntax error is just because i backspaced something while putting the code on this site because i swear in my code sometimes

Comment: Have you checked that there are values in your rooterArray?

Comment: actually i just did funny you should ask, the values are what they are supposed to be, ie 0,1,4,9,16, etc etc

Comment: Once you fix the missing quote, it does work.

Comment: the missing quote was never there in my actual code, it does not fix the issue i promise lol

Comment: Can't you just do `Math.sqrt(n) === Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n))`?

Comment: yes but this is an assignment so not allowed lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `while` loop, the continue condition should be `low <= high && !found` instead of `low < high && !found`.

Comment: Yes, was just writing this up myself, [based on this link](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-search/).